# PHP not encoding quoted_printable_encode correctly

Tags: php, phpmailer, encode, emoticons, quoted-printable

I'm trying to add an emoticon(fire) in email subject. Below is the code I'm using:

```
$subject = "Test email \xF0\x9F\x94\xA5"; 
$charset = "UTF-8";
$subject = sprintf('=?%s?Q?%s?=', $charset, quoted_printable_encode($subject));
// send email....
```

This is adding a fire emoticon to the email subject successfully. But when I try to get the subject from database like:

```
$subject = $themeArray['templateSubject']; // Test email \xF0\x9F\x94\xA5 
$charset = "UTF-8";
$subject = sprintf('=?%s?Q?%s?=', $charset, quoted_printable_encode($subject));
// send email....
```

This is not converting the characters to emoticon. Instead I'm getting the subject in email as
*Test email \xF0\x9F\x94\xA5*

Why its not converting when I get subject from database?

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is more to encoding a subject line than just that. Show the raw string bfore you encode it, and the *encoded* output of that function, not just the result of decoding it afterwards. [This CyberChef config](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Hex('Auto')To_Quoted_Printable()&input=XHhGMFx4OUZceDk0XHhBNQ) shows what should be happening with that string. Alternatively, use PHPMailer (that you tagged this question with), which deals with all this stuff so you don't have to.

Comment: B and Q are different things. Which one you should use depends on your content.